# WPF Data Template Selector based on Generic Types

Tags: wpf, generics, datatemplateselector

I've seen a lot of examples how to use Data Template Selector to show different controls according to the x:TargetType. I want to create an items control that show a RadioButton, TextBox or TextBlock according to the class tyepe.
My class could be like this:

```
public class MyExample<T>
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public Type Type => TypeOf(T)
   public T Value {get;set;}
}
```

I know that the Xaml can't recognize generics and I don't want to create a markup extension for supporting generics, I want to keep it simple. I don't want to create a concrete class for each type.
I know that I can use a Data Trigger to set the content template according to a property (for example type name, or Type Type) but I think that should be an easier way using a Data Template Selector. Can I use the TargetType on the Type Property instead of class type?

Comment: I found this possible solution:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418250/WPF-Based-Dynamic-DataTemplateSelector

I still think that can be easier ways without adding code behind. Regarding performance, what is a better solution: this one or use Data Trigger in Style definition?

Comment: This would be less complicated if - instead of having a generic `T Value` property - you would derive classes with properties like `int Value` and `string Value` etc. You could then benefit from automatic template selection by means of the `DataType` property of your DataTemplates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I use the TargetType on the Type Property instead of class type?

No.

The obvious solution would be to create a sub-type and a corresponding `DataTemplate` for each type of `T`. The implementation for each sub-type would be a one-liner:

```
public class MyExampleInt : MyExample<int> { }
public class MyExampleString : MyExample<string> { }
```

If you don't want to create concrete sub-types for whatever reason, you could use a `DataTemplateSelector` to select a template based on the type of each `MyExample<T>`:

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case MyExample<int> i:
            return IntTemplate;
        case MyExample<string> s:
            return StringTemplate;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: What do you think about the solution I posted ?

Comment: It's fine. I would personally prefer sub-classes but that's just a personal opinion.

Comment: Why? My personal opinion is not creating new sub-classes (models) to support a specific view. Imagine that in the future I want to a different view with a unique control for all the class' types. Why should I need those sub-classes ? I don't think that it is correct to add code behind in the model for the view. Only adding properties and logic in the ViewModel is correct. It is my opinion but I am new with mvvm. I would like to learn from yours opinion

Comment: `MyExampleInt` is not code-behind. It's a (specialized) model class. And you still need to add a `DataTrigger` per type using your current approach.

Comment: Okay. I still don't see the point to hold many specialized models for a specific view. Each view should have its viewmodel, not its models. (At least this is my goal). I can put these classes in the view model as public...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
         
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1" xmlns:syncfusion="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="Red"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ViewModel}"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="MainWindow" d:Height="100" d:Width="150" Width="300" Height="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NumberTemplate">
            <syncfusion:UpDown Name="NumericUpdDown" Value="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxTemplate">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                        <!-- Default Template -->
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" />
                        <!-- Triggers to change Template -->
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type.Name}" Value="Int32">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource NumberTemplate}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type.Name}" Value="String">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TextTemplate}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type.Name}" Value="Boolean">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ItemsControl 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Definitions}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}">
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

The reason that I don't want concrete type class is avoid adding a lot of code, everytime that I add a new type. What do you think about this solution ?